# Что такое ортогональность?

Tags: проектирование, терминология

Я заметил что термин `ортогональность` часто используют неправильно и не нашел в рунете источника, хорошо объясняющего что это такое.

В ответе я хочу:

- Увидеть точное определение понятия `ортогональность` вместе со ссылкой на источник.
- Увидеть примеры кода, показывающие ортогональный и не ортогональный подход.

Comment: Этот термин ранее активно использовался до момента широкого распространения ООП. Например, этот термин использовался часто в языке программирования C. В настоящее время на мой взгляд этот термин не несет самостоятельного семантического значения.

Comment: Здесь есть некое объяснение: http://www.imaladec.com/story/orthogonal_programming

Comment: Вы понимаете, что ортогональный и неортогональный подходы ортогональны друг другу?

Comment: @ixSci для ответа на этот вопрос достаточно прочитать определение.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

На мой взгляд лучше всего об этом написано в книге «Программист-Прагматик. Путь от подмастерья к мастеру. Э. Хант, Д. Тома».

Вот цитата из книги:

> Этот термин был введен в информатике для обозначения некой
>   разновидности независимости или несвязанности. Два или более объекта
>   ортогональны, если изменения, вносимые в один из них, не влияют на
>   любой другой. В грамотно спроектированной системе программа базы
>   данных будет ортогональной к интерфейсу пользователя: вы можете
>   менять интерфейс пользователя без воздействия на базу данных и менять
>   местами базы данных, не меняя интерфейса.

Comment: Оттуда же, но чуть выше по тексту: _"Термин «ортогональность» заимствован из геометрии. Две линии являются ортогональными, если они пересекаются под прямым углом, например, оси координат на графике. В терминах векторной алгебры две такие линии являются независимыми. Если двигаться вдоль одной из линий, то проекция движущейся точки на другую линию не меняется."_

Answer (score 12):

*Ортогональность* - это математический термин, такой же как *сложение*, *умножение* или *вектор*. От того, что слово "vector" используется в программировании, оно не приобретает какие-то новые смыслы, и не становится программистским термином. То же самое и с ортогональностью.

Определение ортогональности звучит следующим образом:

> Если скалярное произведение двух элементов пространства равно нулю, то они называются ортогональными друг другу. (Источник - википедия, или любой учебник по математике).

В случае векторов, они оказываются перпендикулярными друг другу, отсюда и происхождение слова "ортогональность" - греческое "прямой угол".
Из этого следует, что *проекция* одного вектора на другой равна нулю (т.к. косинус угла равен нулю), т.е. в системе координат одного вектора, другой равен нулю.

Когда говорят о каких-то ортогональных сущностях - это означает что эти сущности никак не связаны друг с другом. Т.е. как и в случае с проекцией векторов, одна сущность не оказывает ни какого эффекта на другую.

---

Что касается применимости слова "ортогональность" в коде - то это говорит лишь о не связанности двух систем. Точно также можно было бы говорить о "параллельности" (не пересекаются), или об отсутствии корреляции. Т.е. слово "ортогонален" просто является синонимом "не связан".

Можно сказать что "в С++ алгоритмы ортогональны контейнерам", т.к. у них не никакой прямой связи. Также можно сказать что "логирование должно быть ортогонально UI". В любом случае - это просто использование умного слова "ортогональность", вместо обычного словосочетания "не связанность". Смысл фразы при этом совершенно не меняется.

Comment: Ортогональность - это не отсутствие связи. Это отсутствие взаимного влияния.

Comment: но не в точных науках. Потому что в точных науках бывают односторонние связи. И еще есть связи косвенные, когда некоторый фактор односторонне зависит от двух разных факторов.

Comment: Не говорю уже о таких связях (отношениях), как "часть-целое" или "предмет"-"понятие", где понятие влияния вовсе теряет смысл.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если между двумя объектами есть односторонние связи, но **отсутствует взаимное влияние**, то по [вашему мнению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/481946/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c/483135#comment558411_483135) они ортогональны?

Answer (score 4):

*Определение понятия:*

> Ортогональность на языке программирования означает, что относительно
>   маленький набор примитивных конструкций может быть объединен в
>   относительно небольшое количество способов построить контроль и
>   структуры данных языка. Термин наиболее часто используется
>   относительно наборов команд собрания как ортогональный набор команд.

Подробнее можно прочитать [тут](http://ru.knowledgr.com/07807562/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

На мой взгляд лучше всего объясняет этот термин этот пример:

*Неортогональная система:*

> Предположим, вы находитесь в экскурсионном вертолете, совершающем
>   полет над Гранд-Каньоном, когда пилот, который совершил ошибку,
>   наевшись рыбы за обедом внезапно вскрикивает и теряет сознание. По
>   счастливой случайности это происходит, когда вы парите на высоте 30
>   метров. Вы догадываетесь, что рычаг управления общим шагом несущего
>   винта обеспечивает подъем машины, так что, если его слегка опустить,
>   вертолет начнет плавно снижаться. Однако когда вы пытаетесь сделать
>   это, то осознаете, что жизнь — не такая уж простая штука. Вертолет
>   клюет носом, и вас начинает вращать по спирали влево. Внезапно вы
>   понимаете, что управляете системой, в которой каждое воздействие имеет
>   побочные эффекты. При нажатии на левый рычаг вам придется сделать
>   уравновешивающее движение назад правым рычагом и нажать на правую
>   педаль. Но при этом каждое из этих действий вновь повлияет на все
>   органы управления. Неожиданно вам приходится жонглировать невероятно
>   сложной системой, в которой любое изменение влияет на все остальные
>   управляющие воздействия. Вы испытываете феноменальную нагрузку: ваши
>   руки и ноги находятся в постоянном движении, пытаясь уравновесить все
>   взаимодействующие силы. Органы управления вертолетом определенно не
>   являются ортогональными.

Взято [отсюда](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

Если в двух слова и на пальцах, то на мой взгляд этот термин говорит о слабой свзянности в проектируемой архитектуре.

Comment: Перевод по первой ссылке просто ужасен. Наверное лучше сразу читать весь материал по второй ссылке (https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%84%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0/%D0%9E%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C), а также сссылку http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch04s02.html#orthogonality из текста по первой.

Comment: @Onedev.Link,  если  говорить просто (и своими словами (не соответствует Вашим пожеланиям в вопросе)), то ортогональная система состоит из базовых сущностей, которые во-первых, минимально влияют друг на друга, а во вторых, если какие-то части их семантики похожи, то и синтаксис соответствующих частей тоже схож. / Думаю, в материалах по ссылкам Вы найдете много интересных примеров и разъяснений.

Comment: Стоит заметить, что пример с вертолетом поймут **только те, кто знает** о взаимном влиянии элементов его управления.

Comment: @KromStern тем кому будет не понятно попросту рано в такое влезать :)

Comment: @МстиславПавлов Знание особенностей управления вертолетом и ООП программирование .. весьма ортогональны.

Comment: @KromStern нууу, это как посмотреть :)